# downgrading pip package in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I set up a virtualenv and am trying to install a package where I get the error:

```
error: chardet 4.0.0 is installed but chardet<4.0,>=2.0 is required by {'aiohttp'}
```

Thus I tried to downgrade:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade chardet==3.0.0

Collecting chardet==3.0.0
  Using cached chardet-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Installing collected packages: chardet
  Attempting uninstall: chardet
    Found existing installation: chardet 4.0.0
    Uninstalling chardet-4.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled chardet-4.0.0
Successfully installed chardet-3.0.0
```

Still when I try to install my package I get:

```
error: chardet 4.0.0 is installed but chardet<4.0,>=2.0 is required by {'aiohttp'}
```

I also tried to first uninstall the existing version:

```
pip3 uninstall chardet
```

But I still receive the error:

```
error: chardet 4.0.0 is installed but chardet<4.0,>=2.0 is required by {'aiohttp'}
```

Executing these steps I would expect chardet to downgrade to version 3.0.0 and my package to install. Is there a different way to do this without touching my packages outside of the venv?

Pipdeptree output:

```
$ pipdeptree
pipdeptree==2.0.0
  - pip [required: >=6.0.0, installed: 21.0.1]
pkg-resources==0.0.0
setuptools==53.0.0
wheel==0.36.2
```

Edit:
downgrading indeed worked as expected. I got the error because the package I tried to install required sudo rights and thus by executing it as sudo I left the virtual environment. Downgrading the package globally let me install the package although I wanted to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pipdeptree`, it displays installed packages as a dependency tree, there you can find a bug in chardet with different versions specified.

Comment: i added the pipdeptree output as an edit to the post - however I don't see any information related to chardet there.